# Angular Post and show in html

Tags: html, angular, post

I want to get the NAME data and show html.
MY TS:

```
 this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost/test.php', {idd: this.idd},options)
    .subscribe((data) =>  {
      console.log(data);
      });
```

there are console.log display on tool.

```
HttpResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost/test.php", ok: true, …}
body: Array(2)
0: {ID: "1", NAME: "LLI", EMAIL: "wqriehjfeoghetiogjetlgj", INFO: "hello"}
1: {ID: "2", NAME: "WII", EMAIL: "moiiooofgijtigjw", INFO: "hiiii"}
```

How to get ID value on HTML?
thnak you....

Answer (score 1):

In .ts

```
response: any;

this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost/test.php', {idd: this.idd},options)
    .subscribe((data) =>  {
     this.response = data.body;//TRY THIS
      });
```

In .html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of this.respose">
  {{ item.ID}}
</div>
```

Comment: will show ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: try to parse your data using data = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: I made a fix, try now

Answer (score 0):

Your response is a array containing two sets of records so you have to go though loop to get each set's id something like below :

```
 this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost/test.php', {idd: this.idd},options).subscribe((data) =>  {
            for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
              console.log(data[i].ID);
              console.log(data[i].NAME);
              console.log(data[i].EMAIL);
            }
 });
```